# PHP - Remove decoded HTML entities from string

Tags: php, string, replace, html-entities

I am trying to sanitize a string and have ended up with the following:

> Characterisation of the arsenic resistance genes in  lt i gt Bacillus
>   lt  i gt  sp  UWC isolated from maturing fly ash acid mine drainage
>   neutralised solids

I am trying to remove the lt, i, gt as those are reduced HTML entities which do not seem to be removed. What would be the best way to approach this or another solution that I could look at?

Here is my current solution for now:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFormattedTitle()
{
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ',  filter_var($this->getTitle(), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    return $string;
}
```

And here is an example input string:

```
Assessing <i>Clivia</i> taxonomy using the core DNA barcode regions, <i>matK</i> and <i>rbcLa</i>
```

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you've tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php coupled with http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The telltale `lt` and `gt` in your output tell me that the string you have is actually more like:

"Assessing &lt;i&gt;Clivia&lt;/i&gt; taxonomy using the core DNA barcode regions, &lt;i&gt;matK&lt;/i&gt; and &lt;i&gt;rbcLa&lt;/i&gt;"

when viewed as plain text.

The string you show above is what would show in a browser which would interpret '&lt;' as '<' and '&gt;' as '>'. (These are usually called "HTML entities" and offer a way to encode a character that would otherwise be interpreted as HTML.)

One option is to process like this:

```
$s = "Assessing &lt;i&gt;Clivia&lt;/i&gt; taxonomy …";
$s = html_entity_decode($s); // $s is now "Assessing <i>Clivia</i> taxonomy …"
$s = strip_tags($s); // $s is now "Assessing Clivia taxonomy"
```

But do be aware that strip_tags is an exceedingly naïve function. For example it would turn '1<5 and 6>2' into '12'! So you need to be sure that all your input text is double-HTML encoded as the example is for it to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of filter_var, try strip_tags: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
<?php
  //your input string
  $input_string = 'Assessing <i>Clivia</i> taxonomy using the core DNA barcode regions, <i>matK</i> and <i>rbcLa</i>';

  //strip away all html tags but leave whats inside
  $output_string = strip_tags($input_string);

  echo $output_string;
  //echos: Assessing Clivia taxonomy using the core DNA barcode regions, matK and rbcLa 

?>
```

Comment: I tried that but ended up with:
`Antibiotic resistance profiles of &lt;i&gt;Escherichia coli&lt;/i&gt; isolated from different water sources in the Mmabatho locality`

I now need to remove the &lt, &gt, &i etc...

Comment: In that case, I think @Thomas David Baker is correct that you are seeing the html tags on screen but your underlying data is filled with html entities.  When you showed the example input string, did you copy it from a browser or is it from a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Great, but if didn't clean UTF-8 icon char but it is a great begin. I have added

```
preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $s);
```

Answer (score -1):

Better way is strip_tags();
See a manual here:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php
An example:

```
   public function getFormattedTitle()
    {
        return strip_tags($this->getTitle(), '<i>');
    }
```